# Include images from Google into my application

Tags: javascript, json, html, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I want to add images from google dynamically on button click.

After searching a lot what I found is:

```
var searcher = new google.search.customSearchControl.getImageSearcher();
searcher.setRestriction(
  google.search.customSearchControl.getImageSearcher.RESTRICT_FILETYPE,
  google.search.customSearchControl.getImageSearcher.FILETYPE_JPG
);
searcher.setRestriction(
  google.search.customSearchControl.getImageSearcher.RESTRICT_COLORIZATION,
  google.search.customSearchControl.getImageSearcher.COLORIZATION_GRAYSCALE
);
searcher.execute('London');
```

But I am unable to use this in my code.
Is there a way I can receive the images in a son object?

Comment: You want to add google search Images on button click?

Comment: The API you are using is deprecated, although this seems relevant [google images api](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide#load-the-javascript-api-and-search-module)

Comment: Yes. Is there any way i can load images dynamically from any browser? I can't find any proper API for that

Comment: did you check the link?